# Powershell in SSIS

Tags: powershell, ssis

What would I need to do in order to run a PowerShell script in an SSIS package?

Does PowerShell need to be installed on the SQL server?
How do I actually call the script in SSIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, PowerShell needs to be installed. Then, you can use an [Execute Process Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141166.aspx) to point to the PowerShell executable and give the script as an argument.

Like so:

```
Executable: %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Arguments:  C:\path\to\script.ps1
```